# How to simplify javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, refactoring

Is there any way to simplify this code with loops or anything? I'm a beginner at javascript and my code is horrible. Please don't tell me to convert to jquery or anything.

```
        function dragLeftdropLeft1(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Left");
            document.getElementById('topLeft1').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('topLeft2').style.display = "block";
        }
        function dragLeftdropLeft2(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Left");
            document.getElementById('topLeft2').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('topLeft3').style.display = "block";
        }
        function dragLeftdropLeft3(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Left");
            document.getElementById('topLeft3').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('topLeft4').style.display = "block";
        }
        function dragLeftdropLeft4(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Left");
            document.getElementById('topLeft4').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('topLeft5').style.display = "block";
        }
        function dragLeftdropLeft5(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Left");
            document.getElementById('topLeft5').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('topLeft1').style.display = "block";
        }






        function dragLeftdropRight1(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Left");
            document.getElementById('topRight1').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('topRight2').style.display = "block";
        }
        function dragLeftdropRight2(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Left");
            document.getElementById('topRight2').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('topRight3').style.display = "block";
        }
        function dragLeftdropRight3(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Left");
            document.getElementById('topRight3').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('topRight4').style.display = "block";
        }
        function dragLeftdropRight4(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Left");
            document.getElementById('topRight4').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('topRight5').style.display = "block";
        }
        function dragLeftdropRight5(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Left");
            document.getElementById('topRight5').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('topRight1').style.display = "block";
        }







        function dragRightdropLeft1(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Right");
            document.getElementById('topLeft1').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('topLeft2').style.display = "block";
        }
        function dragRightdropLeft2(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Right");
            document.getElementById('topLeft2').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('topLeft3').style.display = "block";
        }
        function dragRightdropLeft3(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Right");
            document.getElementById('topLeft3').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('topLeft4').style.display = "block";
        }
        function dragRightdropLeft4(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Right");
            document.getElementById('topLeft4').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('topLeft5').style.display = "block";
        }
        function dragRightdropLeft5(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Right");
            document.getElementById('topLeft5').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('topLeft1').style.display = "block";
        }







        function dragRightdropRight1(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Right");
            document.getElementById('topRight1').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('topRight2').style.display = "block";
        }
        function dragRightdropRight2(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Right");
            document.getElementById('topRight2').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('topRight3').style.display = "block";
        }
        function dragRightdropRight3(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Right");
            document.getElementById('topRight3').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('topRight4').style.display = "block";
        }
        function dragRightdropRight4(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Right");
            document.getElementById('topRight4').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('topRight5').style.display = "block";
        }
        function dragRightdropRight5(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Right");
            document.getElementById('topRight5').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('topRight1').style.display = "block";
        }
```

If you want to see the code in action, you can see the full HTML code at http://thomaswd.com/chopsticks. I am trying to make a chopsticks game using HTML and javascript.

Thanks!

Comment: Better to go to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @user2034878 Please remove the question here if you're going to be asking it on CodeReview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well for starters if you have a function

```
 function some_meaningful_name(ev, hand, toNone, toBlock) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData(hand);
            document.getElementById(toNone).style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById(toBlock).style.display = "block";
        }
```

you can call it like

```
some_meaningful_name('Left', 'topRight5', 'topRight1');
```

then, most likely if you put all those strings in arrays, you can probablly just generate all the combos you need with a for loop

Answer (score 1):

You can add one more parameter, the number, if it's not a problem and get this for the first 5 function:

```
    function dragLeftdropLeft(ev, num) {

        ev.preventDefault();

        num2 = num + 1;
        if(num2 == 6)
              num2 = 1

        var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Left");
        document.getElementById('topLeft' + num).style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('topLeft' + num2).style.display = "block";
    }
```